# How to get the contents of a line by its number in shell

Tags: ubuntu, shell, ubuntu-17.04

I need to get the contents of a line by its number I heard of grep and researched the whole forum but got no luck what is the command? E.g I enter a cmd like 'viewlinecontent linenumber file.php' and i will get the line contents.

Answer (score 0):

sed works well here:

```
linenumber=42  # or whatever
sed -n "${linenumber}p" file
```

use `-n` to prevent printing *every* line.
`${linenumber}` specifies the "address range" (a single line), and
`p` to print that line.

[`sed` manual online](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html)

---

If you want your specific syntax, create a shell function:

```
viewlinecontent() {
    sed -n "${1}p" "$2"
}
viewlinecontent 42 file.php
```

Comment: Someday I need to come to terms with sed...

Comment: sed has cryptic one-character commands, no variables, no arithmetic, etc. Most things can be done more readably/maintainably in awk or perl. I only use sed for very short filters: `sed q` == `head -1`; `sed -n '$p'` == `tail -1`; `sed 's/search/replace/g'`; `sed -i 's/\r$//'` == `dos2unix`